# Java spring database application won't quit reference to org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.PoolKeeper is still active why?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, jta

Hello all I have a simple Spring application which will not end as there is still a reference left to org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.PoolKeeper. I include all the references I feel are revelant below does it look ok and has anyone experienced this before?

I ran jstack to see what non daemon threads where running and found the following.

```
"Thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f89b03d8000 nid=0x755 in Object.wait() [0x00007f89bc243000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f89ec57de00> (a org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.PoolKeeper)  at org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.PoolKeeper.run(PoolKeeper.java:55)
    - locked <0x00007f89ec57de00> (a org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.PoolKeeper)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Now I am confused as to why this is happening I include relevant parts of my JPA configuration

```
<bean id="innerDataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource"
    destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jotm" />
    <property name="driverName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value ="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource"
    destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="innerDataSource"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxSize" value="100" />
    <!-- test your jdbc connection before using it -->
    <property name="checkLevelObject" value="${jdbc.checkLevelObject}"/>
    <property name="jdbcTestStmt" value="${jdbc.jdbcTestStmt}"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications typically configure a Spring application context using [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/web-integration.html#web-integration-common), which closes the application context when the Web application is stopped.

Standalone Java applications have to call the [`close`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#close%28%29) method on the application context, which invokes the methods configured in the `destroy-method` attribute while destroying the beans.  Alternatively, call the [`registerShutdownHook`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook%28%29) method to register a shutdown hook that closes the application context on JVM shutdown.

Comment: Thanks Jim

I was looking for the close method but as I was storing the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in a ApplicationContext and not a ConfigurableApplicationContext I never saw the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring file looks correct to me based on the enhydra javadoc (which is sparse on details). I did see a `stopPool()` method in the API. Perhaps try that in your `destroy-method`?